# link to jquery tab

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to link to the second tab in the first paragraph, where it says trip request form. [My Site](http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php)

I have tried

```
<a href="#tabs-2" onclick="$('#tabs-2').trigger('click');">trip request form</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php#tab-2">trip request form</a>
```

Still it is not going to the second tab. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to understand the problem better

Comment: @Beth did you the answer i gave.

Comment: @A.J they aren't working for me

Comment: See the problem is just silly naming mistake

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
<a href onclick="$('#tabs-2').trigger('click');">trip request form</a>
```

or

```
<a href onclick="$('#tabs-2').click();">trip request form</a>
```

Update:

I visited your [site](http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php) , there is no element with id **tab-2**, what you are doing is sending the data to backend as, `href="http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php?tab=tab2"` now in backend you get value of tab as tab2.

And also there is no element that does this functionality. If you don't want to refresh the page try using **Ajax**

Syntax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "contact-testnew.php",
  data : encodeURIComponent("tab=tab2"),
  success: function(data){
  $(body).html(data);   /*right now you get whole page as responce to updating body later just get changed data in response and update only that div*/
}
});
```

Read further about jQuery Ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: What happens when you click on `trip request form` ,  with this code?

Comment: Here is the page http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php It doesn't do anything.  I am using one of them right now. Not sure what I a missing. It seems like it should be simple.

Comment: @Beth: I visited your site you don't have any element by id `tabs-2`, and you are doing `http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php?tab=tab2` on click of anchor that. This means you sending data with you request no other element on page is ding this.

Comment: I am trying different ways and nothing is working. I have the suggestion you made right now. It still isn't working.

Comment: @Beth: First of all you don't have a div by id `tab2` or `tab-2` on first page this id is present on the second page that you get as response, so you can't invoke that element from first page. I have mentioned Ajax in my answer please try that it will help you not refresh the page and load data on fly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use active option of jquery tabs as

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>data1</p>
 </div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>data2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
 <p>data3</p>

</div>
</div>
```

in jquery code

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );//1 is desired tab index and #tabs is tab id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong naming for id. tabs-2 is not valid name. You can try tab2. Then use

```
 <a href="http://www.euroworldvacations.com/contact-testnew.php#tab2">trip request form</a>
```

I hope this will solve your problem